# Using Comparison Operator in Filtering React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Is there any way to use a comparison operator like ">" or "<" to filter react-table either at Column level or global level filtering?

```
export const ColumnFilter = ({ column }) => {
const { filterValue, setFilter } = column
return (
<span>
  Search:{' '}
  <input
    value={filterValue || ''}
    onChange={e => setFilter(e.target.value)}
  />
</span> 
 ) 
}
```

I have a column that has numeric values between 1 and 100. The users will filter the result either lower than the number they enter or larger than the number they enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused that you want to see the lists which are less and greater than the input value.
So If I am not wrong then you want to see the list which value is not equal to the input value. then you can try

```
<input
    value={filterValue || ''}
    onChange={(e) => {
    var newArray = preFilteredRows.filter(function(item) {
  return item !== parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
});

setFilter(newArray)}
}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks. Later I have found this example has the hints, what I am looking for 
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/examples/filtering/src/App.js